# How to check if ajax call exists using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know my title isn't very clear.

For example, this is the structure of my code:

```
if (foo == something) {
  // Ajax call 1, let it be $.ajax("foo1.html") and so on
} else {
  // Ajax call 2, let it be $.ajax("foo2.html") and so on
}
```

How would I test if `$.ajax("foo1.html")` has actually been run?

Please don't tell me to test if `foo == something` again. My actual code is much, much more complicated, so please answer the question from the view of the ajax call.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you right, but jQuery will mix a *Deferred* object into its *jXHR* object and you can just check its state.

```
var resp = $.ajax({});

// somewhere else...
if( resp.state() === 'resolved' ) {
}
```

Other states are `rejected` and `pending`, see http://api.jquery.com/deferred.state/

Of course, you can get all advantages of those *Deferred* objects aswell, like adding more *event handlers* for certain things afterwards (`.done()`, `.fail()`, etc) or just *wait* for the promise to fullfil using `$.when()`.

Comment: yep, exactly what I really wanted.

Comment: is checking `state()` is like checking if the status of `resp` is **200**?

Comment: I didn't work with jQuery for quite a while now, but I'm pretty sure you cannot rely on the status code `200` exactly. The promise will also resolve on status like `304` (cached) and maybe some others. But you can be certain, that the request finished successfully either way.

Answer (score 6):

You can set a callback in your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "foo1.html"
}).done(function() { 
  alert('Done!');
});
```

Comment: well, not exactly what I meant. But still reasonable anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I would set variable before AJAX call and reset it in the success callback like that :

```
var isRunning = true;

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(resp){
      isRunning = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues. I used this code:

```
var isRunning = false; // whether ajax call is running
if(isRunning==false){
   isRunning = true;
   $.ajax({
     // do your stuff
     // make sure you set
     isRunning = false;
     // on success
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the call in a try catch.

if the call to 'foo1' fails because the method does not exist on the server, in the catch call foo two and then three all the way down until you have exhausted all your fall backs.

If you know the method exists and think it will fail, then set a status on it that can be returned if the server fails then handle the return in the ajax callback.

Comment: jQuery does not throw exceptions on failed Ajax requests.

Comment: OK, but checking for a function's existance shouldn't be done with try-catch

Comment: that is fair, but if you are in a state where you think the function should exist but there is a chance it does not, a try catch will make sure you don't break down.

Comment: No, you should should check the `typeof possibleFunction` instead of blindly calling it, try-catch is too much execution overhead

Comment: How do you typeOf a page that is going to be called by ajax? wouldn't it just return that the $.ajax() function exists?